# Encrypt And Decrypt Hash sha256 in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, hash, sha256

I am trying to hash a string in postgresql using sha256 as follow:

`select digest('This is a test','sha256');`

this returns below hashed value:

`\xc7be1ed902fb8dd4d48997c6452f5d7e509fbcdbe2808b16bcf4edce4c07d14e`

Now i want to retrieve my initial string using this hashed value but unable to find anything in the postgres docs regarding it, Any help regarding it will be appreciable.

Comment: I just need to know the possibility of it, so far i have found it to be not possible, What i want is any two-way hashing or encryption that can hash/encrypt text to a smaller string and can be converted back ti the same text as well, That too in postgresSQL

Comment: If you are just looking for compression Postgres does that behind the scenes anyway for character types, see [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/storage-toast.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between *hashing* and *encryption*:

- an encrypted value can be descrypted to get the original back, so encryption is loss-free and two different clear text values will always result in different encrypted values
- a hash cannot be decrypted, because information is lost; different values can result in the same hash, although it is desirable that these "collisions" do not happen too often

Hashing is irreversible, while encryption is reversible.

Now [`digest` is a hashing function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.6.2):

> ```
> digest(data text, type text) returns bytea
> digest(data bytea, type text) returns bytea
> ```
>
> Computes a binary hash of the given `data`.

So you won't be able to recover the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/pgcrypto.html) extension in Postgresql to save data after encryption.

For insertion,

> `INSERT INTO tablename (columnname1, columnname2) VALUES (PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('value1', 'aes_key'), PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('value2', 'aes_key'));`

For fetching,

> `SELECT PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(columnname1::bytea, 'aes_key') as columnname1, PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(columnname2::bytea, 'aes_key') as columnname2 from tablename;`